# Jmeter- How to make a request wait until I get a specific response

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

Request is as :

1. request_a is sent and i get a response as "in progress"
2. Again, request_a is sent and i get a response as "in progress"
3. Again, request_a is sent and i get a response of "complete data"

What happening in my target server when its responds "in progress" is that the server is taking time to cache the data in the server. Here, the 3rd request is returned with complete data.

What I need is : all 3 requests should wait until it gets complete data. So that I can check the real load of the request_a connecting to database-fetching data and giving response

Note: I am checking by clearing the cache manually from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Put your request under the [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter). Use the following [__jexl3() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) as the Condition:

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${response}" != "complete data",)}
   ```
2. Use a suitable Post-Processor to extract the response into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html). For example the following [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) setup would fit:

   [image]
3. That's it, While Controller will loop over until `${response}` variable won't become `complete data`

   [image]

Comment: Hi @Dmitri , The complete data  mentioned is actually a big response. Is it possible to match or give contains, to check a particular string in the response, so that I can identify whether its the complete data response.